Google Cloud Function Golang - io.WriteString not writing to bytes.Buffer in receiver function
I have a pointer receiver in go that stores a pointer to something that implements io.Writer  and then uses io.WriteString in it's functions so that I can either write to a bytes.Buffer, a file, or os.StdOut depending on the situation.
This code creates a non-empty string on my local machine, but not in my google cloud function:

type Output struct {
    Output string `json:"output"`
}

func api(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)
// ......
var out bytes.Buffer
m.runModule(input, &out)
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
output := Output{Output: out.String()}
json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(output)


In google cloud, out.String() returns empty string, though if i write to it using io.WriteString in the same function calling runModule it works. I'm passing it in as a pointer to runmodule, so it's not a copy of the buffer. Has anyone seen this before?

The evidence in the question suggests that m.runModule(input, &out) does not write &out.   Without seeing that function, it's difficult to determine what might be happening.
